Why did detectives decide to destroy this evidence?
Warning, this is a question about the ending of the season. Unmarked spoilers ahead!
In the Amazon Prime TV series Cross, one of the main plots starts with trying to solve a murder (posed as an overdose) of a local activist Emir Goodspeed. Soon, Detective Cross finds, that this is the work of a serial killer (nicknamed later "The Fanboy") and there were at least 10 other victims (not counting "accidental" murders)
But when the killer is apprehended, Detectives Cross and John decide to the destroy crucial evidence:

 Burn the book, created by the killer, containing detailed information about all committed murders.

Moreover, they do it on a live stream while the Fanboy watches this enraged in the interrogation room.
On the one hand, I do understand why they did it: Simply speaking, to seriously piss off the Fanboy: This way from a mastermind serial killer creating a "masterpiece of art", he was turned into a run-off-the-mill crazy dude with "barely" one murder (and kidnapping) behind his belt.
But is there anything else to it? Is annoying (admittedly, very seriously) a serial killer worth denying conviction for the crimes committed to the other victims? Or is (according to Cross and Jim) that a "proper justice" to them  - when the Fanboy is presumed dead, Cross asks "Is this really justice for the victims?".
Are they trying to protect important people blackmailed by the Fanboy?
